# Even the simplest class doesn't compile, "has not been declared

Tags: c++

OK, this is really annoying. I have the (almost) simplest class possible. Two files: a.cpp and a.h
a.h:

```
#ifdef A_H
#define A_H
class a{
  public:
    a();
};
#endif
```

and a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
a::a(){
}
```

and yet it won't compile:

> g++ a.cpp a.cpp:3: error: ‘a’ has not
>   been declared

Clearly, I am doing something wrong, but what?

Fixed, I replaced the #ifdef with #ifndef

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its because

```
 #ifdef A_H
```

needs to be

```
 #ifndef A_H
```

notice the "n", as in if NOT defined.

The former will only compile the code if A_H is defined, which it isn't since you only define it on the next line.

Answer (score 15):

Replace `#ifdef` with `#ifndef`, then try again.

There are some IDEs I find very helpful, that parse the code while you type and show in 'gray' font the code that is not going to be compiled, as of the current macro definitions. Moreover, running

`gcc -E`

followed by the `gcc` arguments you already know, will show you what's the code going to be compiled after preprocessing (macros are resolved by the preprocessor, the initial step of the compilation-building toolchain).